# os_log crashing in MacOS 14 Sonoma

Tags: macos, macos-sonoma, oslog, unified-log

minimum is to create an os_log once in the parent, then, after fork, use an existing os_log instance or create a new one.
Here's my reproduction sample.
It looks like an OS bug, So what is the workaround till its solved and releases.

It is working as expected in macOS version < 14.

```
#include <os/log.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define USE_SWIFT_LOGGER 0  // set to 1 to use Logger() instead of os_log()
#define USE_SHARED_LOG 0    // set to 1 to use a shared os_log instance instead of allocating one for each os_log() call

#if USE_SWIFT_LOGGER
    // log messages using Swift's Logger class instead of calling os_log_... directly
    #include "forktest-Swift.h"
    #define LOG(msg) log_using_logger([NSString stringWithUTF8String:msg])
    const char * logMethod = "Swift's Logger";
#elif USE_SHARED_LOG
    // use a shared os_log instance for all log messages
    static os_log_t log = os_log_create("com.ivanti.forktest", "foo");
    #define LOG(msg) os_log_debug(log, msg)
    const char * logMethod = "shared log";
#else
    // create a new os_log instance for each log message
    #define LOG(msg) os_log_debug(os_log_create("com.ivanti.forktest", "foo"), msg)
    const char * logMethod = "new log instance for each message";
#endif

static void forkTest()
{
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        printf("in child process...\n");
        LOG("in child process...");
        printf("child process done\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("child process pid: %d\n", pid);
    }
}

int main(int arc, const char ** argv)
{
    printf("Log method: %s\n", logMethod);
    LOG("entering main...");
    forkTest();
    LOG("leaving main...");
    return 0;
}
```